# Looking for an example to execute milkrun in last mile

Tags: anylogic

I am a beginner to this Anylogic software. I have tried some ways to make my model work for milkrun in last mile delivery. I used statecharts and modeling library in constructing the logic, but have not successfully cracked the logic. I have looked into anylogic cloud, it helped in learning bits and pieces. But could not find a model in this case. Any ideas or example models would be much helpful to realize my model.
Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of supply chain-type models in the examples that ship with the tool. You can also check out YouTube for in-depth tutorials, [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8gwmF1PhVm-78BknxAB_ZA) is one that could be relevant to your case.